# Com Port Values changed when moved to form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a [distance tracking laser](http://www.micro-epsilon.com/download/manuals/man--optoNCDT-ILR-1181-1182--en.pdf) hooked up to my COM1 port and I am using these settings to initialize the connection:

```
With ServoCalibrater.LaserPort
    .BaudRate = 19200
    .DataBits = 8
    .StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
    .Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
    .StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
    .Close()
    .Open()
    .Write("dt")
End With
```

I then handle the received data with this function: (Reading is a global variable of type double and ErrorMessage is a global variable of type string)

```
Private Sub LaserPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles LaserPort.DataReceived
   ComRecv = True
   Dim TempRead As String

    TempRead = LaserPort.ReadExisting()

    If Not IsNumeric(TempRead) Then
        If Asc(TempRead) = 13 Then
            TempRead = "*No Data*"
        End If
        ErrorMessage = "Laser Error " & TempRead & "...  Please restart application, then turn laser off and back on."
    Else
        Reading = ErrorMessage
    End If
End Sub
```

From here I want to get the `Reading` value onto my Form. I cannot do it directly in the method because it is not thread-safe. So my current attempted solution is to have a timer check the value of `Reading` every tenth of a second and add to the Form. I do so in this tick method:

```
Private Sub tmrMonitor_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrMonitor.Tick
    Dim MeasuredDistance As New clsDimension
    Dim DesiredDistance As New clsDimension

    'Check to see if we've got com with the laser so we can alert the user if not
    If Not ServoCalibrater.ComRecv Then
        LaserError.Text = "No communication received from the laser. Please check to make sure it's turned on."
    Else
        CurrentPosText.Text = Reading
        Refresh()
    End If
End Sub
```

The code above seems to work perfectly when stepping through with the the debugger.
However when the Form is displayed without the debugger the number displayed in CurrentPosText.Text is completely different from the expected value from the laser.

I checked to make sure the laser values were correct by issuing the same commands through [Putty.exe](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

[Here](http://youtu.be/WrjJWbAg_dE) were the consistent results and settings from Putty. (Follow the link and Watch the video)

***TLDR*** Watch [this video!](http://youtu.be/hoPhQiUlcGc)

[image]

How and why does the number I recieve from the COM port change when displayed on the form without the debugger?

Comment: You cannot use ReadExisting() like you do.  That only works when you slow down your program enough so that it reads the entire response.  Like you do with a debugger.  Too few details about the data format, try ReadLine() next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hans is correct.  You must use Readline() in order to get back a single reading back from the com port.  ReadExisting will give you all of whatever is in the com ports buffer.